# KendoUI: How to insert TreeView inside the TabStrip at run time

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I need to add a tree view inside the `tabstrip`.  My scenario is that upon click of a button, I get some data like below.  I need to generate 1 tab per report and put a `treeview` for the `Data` inside the `tab`. Is this possible? If yes, can you please let me know how to do this?  I very much appreciate your help.

JSON Data:

```
[ 
  Report 1: {  Data: [   ] }, 
  Report 2: {  Data: [  ] } 
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is that your final JSON? Is that valid having spaces as attribute name? Wouldn't be better having it like `[ 
    { tab : "Report 1", Data: [  ] }, 
    { tab : "Report 2", Data: [  ] } 
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to propose a little transformation to your JSON so it would look like this:

```
[
    { Id : "Report 1", Data: [ ] }, 
    { Id : "Report 2", Data: [ ] } 
]
```

Where `Id` is the text that we want to show a label for the tab and `Data` is the content of the `tree`.

Start adding an initial (empty) content to each tab.

```
$.each(data, function(idx, elem) {
    elem.Content = "<div>hello</div>";
});
```

So you can do:

```
// Create TabStrip
var ts = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    dataTextField: "Id",
    dataContentField: "Content",
    dataSource: data
}).data("kendoTabStrip");
```

Now for each tab, create the tree:

```
$.each(data, function(idx, item) {
    var c = ts.contentElement(idx);
    $(c).kendoTreeView({
        dataSource : item.Data
    });
});
```

You can see it running here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/x6Acn/1/